# Get auth0 user info after user signs up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, auth0

I want to create auth0 new users from admin panel. Currently, I am using auth0 lock to sign up but now I need to add them to my Database so in order to do that I need the email and auth0 user id.

I am trying to find a way to detect when a new user signs up like The 'authenticated' event that is emitted after a successful sign-in `lock.on('authenticated', function(authResult) { });`

The question is how to get user info after auth0 sign up?

Comment: is there a question? a problem with some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getUserInfo` API of Lock as described [here](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11#2-authenticating-and-getting-user-info)

```
// Listening for the authenticated event
lock.on("authenticated", function(authResult) {
// Use the token in authResult to getUserInfo() and save it to 
localStorage
lock.getUserInfo(authResult.accessToken, function(error, profile) {
if (error) {
  // Handle error
  return;
}

document.getElementById('nick').textContent = profile.nickname;

localStorage.setItem('accessToken', authResult.accessToken);
localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
});
});
```